# coding favicon in base64

Tags: greasemonkey, base64, favicon

hello i'm writing a GM user script
and i want to change the favicon dynamically
changing it the old way is easy but i want to encode it in base64 to avoid hosting it

this is what i have done after hosting the favicon

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.type = 'image/x-icon';
link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
link.href = 'http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/5051/play723.png';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

is there a way to do this with an encoded image
i tried `link.href="url(data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....)"` which lead to nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to drop the url() wrapper. data: is an URL scheme of its own ([RFC 2397](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt)), and it should constitute the value of the href attribute. Of course, only browsers supporting that RFC would be able to understand this link.